# How can I override the active text cursor (Safari)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari

I have set the cursor to be pointer in the CSS. When you click and drag within the div over the text however, the cursor changes to text. ***UPDATE: This only seems to happen in Safari (tested in 9.0.1)***

```css
#test {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color:red;
  display:table;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">testing</div>
```

Comment: No.. it will not change, unless you move your mouse out from the div area while dragging, which is obvious..

Comment: You don't understand. I'll edit the question :)

Comment: I am editing your question so that you can test it properly, as per my comments..

Comment: Now run the snippet and try moving your cursor, outside the _red_ area.. Then only you'll find the `pointer`.. :)

Comment: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/chrome-text-select-cursor-on-drag    read this

Comment: Yes.. Now if you see, the cursor changes to pointer once you move out and here width of the `#test` does not go to complete screen.. Hope you are getting the difference,,

Comment: Interestingly the three major browsers each handle this slightly differently. In Firefox leaving the box goes to the `default` pointer. In Chrome it goes to `text` and in IE/Edge it stays as `pointer`.

Comment: @Cola That is the desired behavior I am after!

Comment: @Khalos It seems as though my question only applies to Safari (tested 9.0.1). You are correct :) Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

---

Just use the cursor property on hover:

```
    #test:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```

Comment: This does not accomplish the behavior I'm after.

Comment: sorry - i must be confused about the behavior you're getting

Comment: I mean that when you put the cursor on the div, click, and drag, the cursor changes to text. How can I override it? Thank you for your answer :)

Comment: does this fiddle show the same problem? you mean drag on the portion of the div that isn't text? [http://jsfiddle.net/8nyEE/ ]

Comment: I mean that when you hover on the `.hand` div, click, and drag, the cursor changes to text. (I am experiencing this in Safari and I haven't yet tested other browsers).

Comment: I have tested it in other browsers, it appears as though my question only applies to Safari because your code seems to have the desired behavior *in every browser except Safari (tested 9.0.1)*

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:active` pseudo class for that:

```css
#test {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color:red;
  display:table;
}
#test:active{
  cursor: auto;/*changes to text-cursor*/
}
```

```html
<div id="test">testing</div>
```

Comment: Update for you, my question only applies to Safari 9.0.1. Thank you for writing an answer ;)

Comment: Yes, but this answer doesn't work in Safari which was the only browser experiencing the problem in the first place. It is your choice to delete the answer :) Thank you for writing.

Answer (score 1):

A bit of JS could do it :

```js
document.onmousedown = function () {
    document.getElementById("parent").style.cursor = "pointer"
}

document.onmouseup = function () {
    document.getElementById("parent").style.cursor = "default"
}
```

```css
#test {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color:red;
  display:table;
}
#parent {
  height: 100px;
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent"><div id="test">testing</div></div>
```

Comment: Update for you, my question only applies to Safari 9.0.1. Thank you for writing an answer ;)